# Merge vs MergeDeep

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I've been looking into the performance of some of my reducers and noticed some weird behavior which was contrary to how I though merge and mergeDeep work. I thought that merge and mergeDeep work the same except that after comparing the key/value of the top level for equality then merge stops but mergeDeep keeps digging.

example:

```
let obj1 = Map({
    a: Map({
        b: Map({
            c: 10
        })
    })
});

let obj2 = obj1;

obj1 = obj1.mergeIn(['a'], Map({
    b: Map({
        c: 10
    })
}));

console.log(obj1.toJS()) // { a: { b: { c : 10 } } }
console.log(obj1 === obj2) // false
```

vs

```
let obj1 = Map({
    a: Map({
        b: Map({
            c: 10
        })
    })
});

let obj2 = obj1;

obj1 = obj1.mergeDeepIn(['a'], Map({
    b: Map({
        c: 10
    })
}));

console.log(obj1.toJS()) // { a: { b: { c: 10 } } }
console.log(obj1 === obj2) // true
```

Can anyone explain why they don't both return true? And if I have to use mergeDeep won't this be a huge performance penalty or will the fact that I won't re-render as often outweigh it?

Comment: I actually don't now the reason but if you want to use equality check (for example should update checks inside react component) over the immutable data structures, you need to use Immutable.is(obj1, obj2).

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the way JS compares objects. Here is an example of this peculiar behavior:

```
const a = {
  dog: 'fido'
}

const b = {
  dog: 'fido'
}

const c = a;

console.log(a === b); // false
console.log(a === c); // true
```

This illustrates the difference between a regular merge and a deep merge. It would be suggested to compare specific key/values of properties you are watching rather than comparing equality of the whole object for optimizing performance.